# How to recover files from an iPhone backup without restoring to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, backup

I have a backup file of an iPhone that was backed up to a Mac. It was not an iCloud backup.

Is there a way to browse that backup on the Mac and recover selected photos, etc.? (Without restoring it to another iPhone.)

The backup is encrypted, and I know the password.
The backup is of an iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer), which runs on macOS and Windows, can open iPhone backups. You need to know the password if the backup has been encrypted.

Disclaimer: I’m a satisfied customer of MacroPlant LLC, and have no financial or other ties.

Comment: I have not found a good free one (yet) as although there are quite a few programs around their "trial" or "free" version as you would probably expect seems to have limits on what is possible such as number or size transfer restrictions or worse still allowing a read-only  view until you purchase. I'll admit I've not looked too hard though for a free solution just yet.

Answer (score 0):

[iBackup Extractor](https://www.wideanglesoftware.com/ibackupextractor/) is another solution which can access encrypted backups (you'll need to enter your encryption password). You can browse your backup content and extract 20 items with the free trial (further extractions require a purchased licence).

The extracted files are copied out to your Mac, so you don't need to restore the backup to your iPhone.